# Faster way to remove header from really large binary file

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have several large binary files, 10+ GB, that have a header of variable length. I want to remove the header and rewrite the file without it. My current solution is to take in a chunk of the file and look for the end of the header then truncate the information, write it to file, then read and write the rest of the file. This worked on a small test file but when doing the actual work file it takes a really really long time, in fact the first test case is still running at the time of this post. Is there a more efficient way to handle this simple task?

```
filename="input_with_header.bin"
chunksize=2048
found=False
i=0
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    outputF=open("headerless.bin",'wb')
    chunk = f.read(chunksize)
    while not found:
        if chunk[i:i+12] == b'HEADER_END\r\n':
            found=True
            i+=12
            chunk=chunk[i:]
        else:
            i+=1
    outputF.write(chunk)
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk:
            break
        outputF.write(chunk)
        outputF.flush()
    outputF.close()
```

Comment: 2K is a really small buffer.

Comment: The large file just finished, so the process is sound. I'll try increasing the buffer size.

Comment: Larger buffer size certainly helped! I'll have to bench mark which buffer size makes the most sense. Hopefully someone has a really slick method of doing this still.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid the rewriting part, I'm afraid it's impossible, since most file systems don't support "moving" file data - only reading, writing/appending and, if you're lucky, truncating.